# Java MouseListener not firing events on click

Tags: java, swing, listener

I have created a class that extends the Component class. Set up the paint methods, etc etc. Now I just added a mouse listener to the class and it doesn't work. Here is the mouse listener class:

```
public class RobotDetailsMouseListener implements MouseListener {

private Robot robot;
private boolean showDetails;

public RobotDetailsMouseListener(Robot robot) {
    this.robot = robot;
    showDetails = true;
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("This is being ran!");
    robot.setShowDetails(showDetails);
    showDetails = !showDetails;
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("Mouse is over a robot");

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("Mouse is over a robot");

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("Mouse is over a robot");

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("Mouse is over a robot");

}
}
```

This is being added to the component via the `this.addMouseListener()` method, and I'm passing it a new object of type `RobotDetailsMouseListener()`:

```
this.addMouseListener(new RobotDetailsMouseListener(this));
```

The component itself moves around the screen a lot (it simulates an autonomous robot over a 2d plane). Could that have anything to do with it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so may be when you try to click on component it's change position before you release the mouse button. so may be change mouseClicked to mousePress event

Comment: In the above code, I've got a println statement on mousePressed. Still nothing! :(

Comment: Could you put your component code? I see here that you add the listeren to instance of Robot (java.awt.Robot?) class.

Comment: so Robot class what it's the class from what class are you inherit it

Comment: No, it's a class I've made called Robot. It inherits from the JPanel class now. I'd rather avoid it; it's lengthy and I doubt it will be of much help to you guys.

Comment: *"I doubt it will be of much help to you guys"* - Can't be any less help then what you've provided

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Your mouselistener looks fine, it should at least be printing stuff to the console. The problem is in how it is attached to the component or how the component is used. That's the code you need to show.

Comment: try this.addMouseListener(new RobotDetailsMouseListener(null)); instant of this.addMouseListener(new RobotDetailsMouseListener(this)); or else create object for Robot and pass as argument

Comment: In the end I just added a mouse listener to the JPanel everything is painted on, and it returns me anything under the mouse's co-ordinates. Thanks for the help guys :)